# How to connect a prometheus through openshift

Tags: openshift

how to connect the Prometheus through Openshift. The log metrics should be visible in Prometheus.
we have tried locally it is working there but we want in Openshift environment.

Comment: Please add more information what you want to do. OpenShift has the route and service for Prometheus which is used for Cluster Monitoring. Do you want to know how to give permissions to access Prometheus?

Comment: Yes...I want to connect the Grafana through the Prometheus Metrics and I want to see these metric logs in grafana

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the Prometheus using Grafana requires `cluster-monitoring-view` permission to get metrics on the Prometheus.

1. Create Service Account on a project.

```
$ oc create sa <Service Account Name>
```

2. Give the role `cluster-monitoring-view` to the SA.

```
$ oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-monitoring-view -z <Service Account Name>
```

3. Add Token of the SA as a bearer token into a prometheus datasource on Grafana.

```
$ oc sa get-token <Service Account Name>
```

```
"Authorization: bearer <TOKEN>"
```